# Filter table row in polymer element

Tags: jquery, polymer, tablefilter

I am having a table in my polymer element and i want it filters the row according to the keywords provided in the input field

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
<template>
<paper-input label="Search" floatingLabel="false" class="search-main" on-keyup="{{search}}"></paper-input>
<table id="table">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Middle Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Cr</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>keety</td>
            <td>cros</td>
            <td>bran</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer('my-element', {
        search: function() {
            var rows = this.$.table.querySelector('tr');
            var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ')',
            reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
            text;

            $(rows).show().filter(function() {
                text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
                return !reg.test(text);
            }).hide();                  
       }
    })
    ;
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

not getting any console error but filter is not working

I'm new to polymer, so please tell what am i doing wrong?

Comment: According to Polymer documentation, `this.$.table` reference should refer to element with id `table` however your table doesn't have an id attribute. Try to change `<table>` to `<table id="table">`.

Comment: oh that is in my code, accidently it get deletd here by me...i have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Method [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) returns only the first element, which in your case is `<tr>` in `<thead>`. You need to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead and select only `<tr>` in `<tbody>`.

Replace:

```
var rows = this.$.table.querySelector('tr');
```

with:

```
var rows = this.$.table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
```

Also it doesn't seem that `$(this).val()` is the correct way to access value of `<paper-input>`. You need to change your `<paper-input>` to:

`<paper-input label="Search" floatingLabel="false" value="{{searchVal}}"  class="search-main" on-keyup="{{search}}"></paper-input>`

Then you will be able to access its value as `this.searchVal` instead of `$(this).val()` in your code.

Comment: have tried your code but still my rows are not filtered

Comment: yes in case of <paper-input> we cant use $(this).val()...i have posted answer of my ques but thanx to point out the error

Answer (score 0):

```
 <polymer-element name="my-element">
 <template>
 <paper-input label="Search" floatingLabel="false" value="{{valHeader}}"    class="search-main" on-keyup="{{search}}"></paper-input>
 <table id="table">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Middle Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Cr</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>keety</td>
        <td>cros</td>
        <td>bran</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </template>
 <script>
Polymer('my-element', {
  search: function() {
            var rows = this.$.table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
            var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim(this.valHeader).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ')',
            reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
            text;

            $(rows).show().filter(function() {
                text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
                return !reg.test(text);
            }).hide();                  
       }
})
;
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

`{{valHeader}}` creates a property inside your note-list elelemt which is bound to the input value of the paper-input and we can access it using `this.valHeader`